# unable to save value from xml to tmp object in MIRTH javascript

Tags: javascript, mirth

this works : tmp['MSH']['MSH.4']['MSH.4.1'] = "xyz";

tmp[['MSH']['MSH.4']['MSH.4.1']] = "xyz"; //this doesnt work.

I am trying to get the value from json as string with brackets

I need that brackets or any other solution

I am trying to save the value in following location of HL7 message.
pls help

LINE NUMBER:    45
DETAILS:    TypeError: Cannot read property "MSH.4.1" from undefined
    at 6520e152-1c7a-41bc-9642-e5f97cd11d98:45 (doTransform)
    at 6520e152-1c7a-41bc-9642-e5f97cd11d98:48 (doScript)
    at 6520e152-1c7a-41bc-9642-e5f97cd11d98:50
    at com.mirth.connect.server.transformers.JavaScriptFilterTransformer$FilterTransformerTask.call(JavaScriptFilterTransformer.java:134)
    at com.mirth.connect.server.transformers.JavaScriptFilterTransformer$FilterTransformerTask.call(JavaScriptFilterTransformer.java:100)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: tmp is an XML Object, so when you try tmp [[ ... ]] what are you trying to achieve? If you need brackets, read the value and add brackets afterwards such as tmp[..]="{" + value + "}", is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
tmp['MSH']['MSH.4']['MSH.4.1'] = '[xyz]';
```